# JavaFX: Binding a property to a label does not update

Tags: java, user-interface, binding, properties, javafx

I'm trying to bind the value of an IntegerProperty (that I cast into a StringProperty in my getter) to a javafx label. However, the value does not change.

In the Head of my class:

```
private IntegerProperty totalMessaged;
```

In the constructor of the class:

```
this.totalMessaged = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
```

The getter from the class:

```
public StringBinding getTotalMessaged() { 
    return this.totalMessaged.asString(); 
}
```

In the method that I use to increade the property:

```
this.totalMessaged.add(1);
```

In the controller class:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    this.sentLabel.textProperty().bind(ClientHandler.getInstance().getTotalMessaged());
}
```

When I start the program the label will be set to 0, so the binding first seems to work. However, when it calls the method to increase the property, the property does not increase by 1, it stays 0 - the label doesn't change and if I print out the value to the console after using this.totalMessaged.add(1); it'll still say that this property is 0. 
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Use converter to convert form String to Integer.

In controller:

```
sentLabel.textProperty().bindBidirectional(ClientHandler.getInstance().totalMessagedProperty(), new NumberStringConverter());
```

In model:

```
private final IntegerProperty totalMessagedProp = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

public int getTotalMessaged() {
    return totalMessagedProp.get();
}

public IntegerProperty totalMessagedProperty() {
    return totalMessagedProp;
}

public void setTotalMessaged(int totalMessaged) {
    this.totalMessagedProp.set(totalMessaged);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the NumberStringConverter came in handy later, but my problem was another that you couldn't see from the source i offered. I didn't user Platform.runlater in the task in which I increased the value, that's why it didn't work somehow. Totally my bad, but thank you anyway.